# Using a bitwise function and then attempting to do the two's complement without success

Tags: python-3.x, mips, twos-complement, bitwise-xor

I'm presently working on a project and I'm at a bit of a stopping point, not knowing if what I'm presently seeing is something that is messing up other parts of my code that follows.  In summary, I'm using the XOR bitwise function in python 3.x (whatever the newest one is) and the result that I'm getting is -523003604.  This decimal, when translated to hex is -1F2C66D4.  What I'm after is the signed two's complement of -523003604 which is E0D3992C in hex.  I'm unsure if this is affecting the code that I have that comes after all of this.
All of what I'm doing is taking in a text file that has 8-bit hex code instructions, I'm converting them to 32-bit binary, and then working with the given information, therein.

my two's complement function

```
def twosComp(d, bits):  # decimal to twos complement
    if (d & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0:
        d = d - (1 << bits)
    return (d)
```

the part where I'm doing the XOR using bitwise

```
elif (tempBin[26:] == '100110'):  # XOR
    count_total += 1
    count_alu += 1
    arrayPc += 4
    array32[rd] = array32[rs] ^ array32[rt])
    # array32[rd] = twosComp(array32[rd], 16)  #doesn't do anything
    print(f'{array32[rd]}, {array32[rs]}, {array32[rt]}')
    ins = f'xor ${rd}, ${rs}, ${rt}'
    print(f'In MIPS: {ins}')
    print(f'Updated Register: ${rd} = {array32[rd]}')
    print(f'Updated pc = {arrayPc} \n')
    #time.sleep(10)
```

what I'm getting

```
-523003604, -23456, 523058508
In MIPS: xor $14, $8, $9
Updated Register: $14 = -523003604
Updated pc = 24
```

I'm more than willing to provide more code/the whole code if you need to look at things and see how it runs. I have other issues at the moment too, but I'm trying to take things one step at a time and I'm starting with the first thing that I see executed that isn't correct and going from there.

Thank you

Comment: We don't usually write hex numbers with a `-` sign.  `-523,003,604` is literally `E0D3992C` in hex.  The negation of `-523,003,604`, is `+523,003,604`, which in hex is `1F2C66D4`, and whose two's complement is `E0D3992C`.

Comment: so then i'd need to multiply it by negative 1 and THEN do the two's complement, is that what you're saying?

Comment: If I knew what you're trying to do I'd provide an answer.  My only point is that we don't usually refer to hex constants with a `-`, instead to write a negative hex number, we make sure the sign bit is set.  When interpreted as a signed data type in two's complement, we can see that `E0D3992C` is a negative number b/c the sign bit is set (1), and that `1F2C66D4` is positive b/c the sign bit is clear (0).

Comment: but @erik-eidt the signed two's complement of -523003604 is E0D3992C.  The signed two's complement of the positive version of that is 1F2C66D4. https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html?x=-523069140

Comment: I'm taking in 8-bit hex commands, converting them to binary, breaking out the assembly instructions from there and then executing those commands using what I have.  This MIPS program runs in MARS, but I'm attempting to replicate the same thing in python.

Comment: Ok, that's super confusing.  Please ignore the highly unusual negative hex form from that website. Let's suffice it to say that the representation of `-523,003,604` in two's complement form (and in 32-bits in hex) is `E0D3992C`.

Comment: Yes, but MIPS instructions as a whole are not treated as signed.  Since an instruction is a collection of bit fields, unsigned is the most reasonable way to think of them as a whole 32-bit number.  (Most of the fields of an instruction are unsigned, but some immediates are sign extended in use.)

Comment: So, I figured it out.  The -523003604 was okay.  MARS handles it the same way.  As for my other errors, in my "complete" code, I missed the fact that I didn't parse out a SLT instruction AND the SLL function that I had needed to be reset to 0 after it executed 32 times.  All in all, I got it to work.  I appreciate your insight though @erik-eidt and thank you for the lesson you were teaching.